# GlassFish v3 and Solr 3.6 - No /solr/home in JNDI

Tags: solr, glassfish

I'm using Solr 3.6.1 with GlassFish v3.1.2.  I've installed it by dropping `dist/apache-solr-3.6.1` into auto-deploy after setting the following JVM options:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Dsolr.solr.home=/mysolrhome/
asadmin create-jvm-options -Dsolr.data.dir=/mysolrhome/data
```

However, in the GlassFish log I notice that it prints out

```
INFO: No /solr/home in JNDI
INFO: using system property solr.solr.home: /mysolrhome/
```

It looks like I should be able to define the Solr home directory through JNDI rather than JVM options. I'd prefer using JNDI if possible.  So I tried creating a custom JNDI resource of type `java.lang.String` (Factory class: `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory`) with the name `solr/home` and a single additional property without a name with a value of `/mysolrhome`. Upon redploying the Solr war file it still logs that `/solr/home` was not found. I also tried creating a JNDI custom resource with the name `/solr/home` with the same outcome.

What's the correct way of setting the `solr/home` JNDI for Solr under Glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

Set a system property 'solr.solr.home' in Glassfish console

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrGlassfish

Or set an env-entry 'solr/home' in domain.xml

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/04/glassfish-set-web-env-entry.html

Comment: As I had stated in my question, I was looking for a way to do it with JNDI.